# Can't import tensorflow.keras in VS Code

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-code

I'm running into problems using tensorflow 2 in VS Code. The code executes without a problem, the errors are just related to pylint in VS Code. 
For example this import `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense` gives a warning "Unable to import 'tensorflow.keras.layers'pylint(import-error)". Importing tensorflow and using `tf.keras.layers.Dense` does not produce an error. I'm just using a global python environment (3.7.2) on Windows 10, tensorflow is installed via Pip.

Comment: Your pylint installed in same environment as you in 3.7.2?

Comment: I thing so. It is located in C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts and I pointed VS Code to that path.

Comment: It's also possible that Pylint simply doesn't understand tensorflow 2 and its package layout (Pylint has known issues handling some other projects that contain extension modules like PyQt5).

Comment: Seems to be that way. Telling pylint to ignore tensorflow.keras removes the error messages, which is not a real solution but good enough for now.

Comment: How do I configure pylint on vscode to ignore this tensorflow error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved after upgrading to TensorFlow 2.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000250/import-tensorflow-keras-could-not-be-resolved-after-upgrading-to-tensorflow-2)

Answer (score 46):

The imports that were causing the issue for me:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

The way I resolved it:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: This has done it for me.

Comment: Also did the trick for me!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by pressing `ctrl+shift+P` in Visual Studio Code, searching `Python: Select Interpreter`, and choosing the main environment.

More detailed information can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: This actually works even if you were using a python virtual environment, turns out the interpreter was using the global environment, hence the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of importing from tensorflow.keras import everything from "keras" solely. From one of the tensorflow versions until now there is a common error.
For instance:
Instead of

```
From tensorflow.keras import layers, models
```

Write this:

```
From keras import layers,models
```

Answer (score 2):

My way to work with that: The problem is related to the custom import system in tf2 (see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/818#issuecomment-537143000)). A work around for this is possible ([Windows](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32982#issuecomment-541356629), [Linux](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32982#issuecomment-545414061)) which basically tricks VS Code to directly import tensorflow_core and don't use the custom lazy loader. If you just want to remove the red lines (as this is only an editor-problem), use

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": 
    ["--ignored-modules=tensorflow.keras"]
```

Comment: I did this but still see yellow underline for tensorflow.keras, i m on a mac os x.

Comment: I changed this in settings.json and this didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue. I solved it by installing `keras` as a new package and then I changed all packages name removing the prefix `tensorflow.`. So in your case after installing `keras` you should replace `tensorflow.keras.layers` with `keras.layers`

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
```

with

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
```

Answer (score -5):

Its just better to use pycharm instead of vscode. This issue does not exist in pycharm. However, if you are insistent on using vscode, then the import statements have to be changed as follows.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: That was not the question. That's the same as answering "using a bike is better" when I ask for a way to change my cars spark plugs.

Comment: Actually I am using pycharm, and the problem is there.