# Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved after upgrading to TensorFlow 2.8.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

TensorFlow 2.8 was recently released and I installed it as soon as it was out. I really need it for support of higher NumPy versions and a few new features. However, after installing it in my conda environment with

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

neither PyCharm nor VSCode can no longer resolve the import `from tensorflow.keras import ...`.

The imports themselves seem to work at runtime, but because the import cannot be resolved I can't make use of code completion, visualizing signatures of functions and etc. Has anybody encountered a similar issue?

everything was working with TF 2.7 - the version I had before.

Note: I'm using Python 3.8

Vs Code
[image]

PyCharm
[image]

I tried to check the versions through the PyCharm interpreter tab and this is what I saw. For some reason PyCharm isn't aware that there are versions after 2.0 (I have the latest version of pip installed in that environment). I'm guessing this is related, but not sure what to do with that.

[image]

Answer (score 37):

I had the same problem and resolved it by importing it as

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
```

Comment: Only few statements work in this fashion. I tried  `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator`  and `from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator` and neither of them worked for me.

Comment: Which Python interpreter do you use? 
I use Python 3.8

Comment: worked for me ! How do you know to do this *t ?!
tensorflow.python.keras import layers

Comment: You mean the format of the comment?

Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more about formatting…

Comment: I have switched from working on my local machine to Google Collab and I use the following imports: 

```python
import mlflow\ 
import mlflow.keras\
import mlflow.tracking\
from mlflow import pyfunc\
from mlflow.models import Model\

import numpy as np\ 
import pandas as pd\ 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt\ 

from keras.layers import LSTM\
from keras.layers import Dense\
from keras.models import Sequential\

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler\
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a bug in the current version of tensorflow, as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144).

You can work around it by either

1. modifying the file `site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py` as described in [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144#issuecomment-985179600) from the referenced issue or
2. using `import keras.api._v2.keras as keras` since this seems to be the exact package tensorflow loads itself. (Though you need to reference the protected member `_v2` here, which is against python conventions.)

The reason here is that tensorflow tries to load the keras module in a lazy fashion, which means that it holds only a reference to the module until the module is used. Only then the keras module will be actually loaded. Therefore IDEs only know about the reference tensorflow holds to the keras module and not its content.

Comment: It seems to be a different problem.  `import tensorflow; tensorflow.keras` and `import tensorflow.keras`(or `from tensorflow.keras import ...`) are resolved differently by IDE. The second one is based on `tensorflow.__path__`, while the first one is based on `tensorflow.keras`.

Comment: See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/54104#issuecomment-1067102133

Answer (score 12):

I see the problem in Google Colab as well.  Although running the code works just fine. It's just an IDE complaint that supposedly it cannot find the imports.  Very strange. I hope someone from the TensorFlow team gives feedback soon.

[image: Could not be resolved error]

Answer (score 2):

Resolving

```py
import tensorflow
foo = tenstorflow.keras.foo
# if foo is a submodule but not an attribute, this will fail
```

and

```py
from tensorflow.keras import foo
# if foo is an attribute, this is (roughly) equivalent to
import tensorflow.keras
foo = tenstorflow.keras.foo
# if foo is a submodule but not an attribute, this is (roughly) equivalent to
import tensorflow.keras.foo as foo
```

are different.

The first one need `tensorflow` has `keras` attribute with correct type statically during type checking.

But the second one need `tensorflow.__path__` contains `keras` module statically during type checking.

BTW, for `from tensorflow import keras`:
If `tensorflow` has `keras` attribute, then it uses the attribute, otherwise it import `keras` as a submodule.

Theoretically, the second one should only work for `2.2.0 <= TF < 2.6.0`, which has `tensorflow/keras` folder. Because `tensorflow/keras` should be removed in TF 2.6 according to [TF 2.6 Release Log](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#release-260), otherwise `from tensorflow import keras`(`tensorflow.keras` backed by the `keras` PIP package) will be different from `import tensorflow.keras as keras`(`tensorflow/keras` backed by `tensorflow/python/keras`).

In fact, however, the second one works for `2.2.0 <= TF < 2.8.0`, since `tensorflow/keras` is not removed until TF 2.8. Interestingly, `tensorflow/python/keras` is not removed yet (Release 2.9.1), violating the claim in TF 2.6 Release Log that "... will be removed in future release (2.7)".

The first one is broken for `TF >= 2.5.0` because of keras lazy loading introduced in TF 2.5, and haven't been fixed yet (Release 2.9.1) though related commits have been merged into master branch.

See
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/54104
and
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/e65b68a0914408118995d2f8b55c4286859362f8

See also https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/54104#issuecomment-1067102133

Answer (score 2):

You can create a symlink in tensorflow directory pointing to keras sources like below:

```
cd ./virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.x/site-packages/tensorflow
ln -s ../keras/api/_v2/keras/ keras
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```py
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
```

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when there is a naming conflict in TensorFlow while trying to import Keras. It can be resolved by modifying the **`__init__.py`** file in the TensorFlow package. Follow the steps below to resolve the issue:

1. Locate the **`__init__.py`** file within your TensorFlow installation. The file path is typically **`site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py`**.

   Alternatively, you can quickly open the file by clicking on the word "tensorflow" in your import statement and pressing **`CTRL`** (or **`CMD`** on Mac) simultaneously. This should navigate you directly to the **`__init__.py`** file.
2. Open the **`__init__.py`** file in a text editor.
3. Look for the section of code around line 387 that mentions the **`keras`** module.
4. Replace this existing code block

   ```py
   _keras_module = "keras.api._v2.keras"
   keras = _LazyLoader("keras", globals(), _keras_module)
   _module_dir = _module_util.get_parent_dir_for_name(_keras_module)
   if _module_dir:
     _current_module.__path__ = [_module_dir] + _current_module.__path__
   setattr(_current_module, "keras", keras)
   ```
5. with the following modified code:

   ```py
   import typing as _typing
   if _typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
     from keras.api._v2 import keras
   else:
     _keras_module = "keras.api._v2.keras"
     keras = _LazyLoader("keras", globals(), _keras_module)
     _module_dir = _module_util.get_parent_dir_for_name(_keras_module)
     if _module_dir:
       _current_module.__path__ = [_module_dir] + _current_module.__path__
     setattr(_current_module, "keras", keras)
   ```
6. Save the changes to the **`__init__.py`** file.

Now, when you import Keras from TensorFlow, the naming conflict should be resolved. This modification allows the correct import of the Keras module within TensorFlow.

this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras
models = tf.keras.models
...
```

It works well for auto completion.

Comment: ```from keras import ...``` works for current version (2.13)