# Conda env M1 Macos causing "No module named 'keras'" with no error during execution on DataSpell

Tags: python, tensorflow, intellij-idea, dataspell

So, I have a conda env with the following packages installed:

```
tensorboard               2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-deps           2.9.0                         0    apple
tensorflow-estimator      2.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-macos          2.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metal          0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
```

and my IDE (DataSpell) signals the following:
[image]

However, If i run the code, no error whatsoever is thrown, so I suppose that I'm missing some configuration, any idea?

Comment: The same is happening lately in Google Colab (tf 2.9), with the warning `Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)` but everything still works.

Comment: @ClaudiaR grazie claudia, good to know that I'm not the only one ahah

Comment: The solution here seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838765/14774959

Comment: @ClaudiaR grazie claudia, the second one worked

Comment: @ClaudiaR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73465536/discriminator-predicts-almost-always-1 in case you want to try... btw, can we exchange a contact, maybe we can help each other without passing through SO

Answer (score 1):

Please import the keras from tensorflow as below:

```
from tensorflow import keras

#Or

from tensorflow import keras as k
```

Comment: hi there, sorry for the delay... thank for the answer, however this only fixes half of the problem as for example subclassing from keras layer leads to `'CustomLayer' object is not callable`, as if `keras.layers.Layer` is not callable... (also clicking over `keras.layers.Concatenate` lead to a "Cannot find declaration to go to")

Comment: Can you please share some more reproducible code to understand and fix this error.

Comment: just use the code you have provided, add `x = k.layers.Concatenate()` and use CMD/Ctrl+click over the "Concatenate", and you will see that the IDE can't find any reference... however, `import keras.api._v2.keras as keras` works fine as reported by claudia in the comment section

Comment: Please have a look at this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/80e479959b83879ce00340d0a86b04fc/73405532.ipynb). You can check [tf.keras.layers.Concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Concatenate) api for more details.

Comment: the problem occurs with TF 2.9 as reported on the question

Comment: Hi @AlbertoSinigaglia, It's the same output even using TF 2.9 also.