# Discriminator predicts almost always 1

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network

I have a GAN that aims to reproduce the paper CycleGAN. However, even though everything is implemented correctly (as for some basic dataset it works), with the Facade Dataset the discriminator predicts the following:

```
print(f"Segm: {tf.reduce_mean(discriminator_segm(segmented_test[0:10])).numpy()}, {tf.reduce_mean(discriminator_segm(generator_real_to_segm(real_test[0:10]))).numpy()}")
print(f"Real: {tf.reduce_mean(discriminator_real(real_test[0:10])).numpy()}, {tf.reduce_mean(discriminator_real(generator_segm_to_real(segmented_test[0:10]))).numpy()}")

# Segm: 0.9463781714439392, 0.9564124941825867
# Real: 0.9635561108589172, 0.8240727782249451
```

In other words, it considers the generated output as good as the ground truth

This makes no sense, as the best guess, if the generated images were identical to the ground truth (which are not, are very far from being similar), should be to predict 0.5

At this point, I tried to train the discriminator many more times than the generator, with no difference (still get the accuracy near 90%)

If you need, even though it's a bit long, this is the training loop:

```
def train(EPOCHS = 400, batch_size = 4):
    real_train_batched = real_train.reshape((-1, batch_size, *real_train.shape[1:]))
    segmented_train_batched = segmented_train.reshape((-1, batch_size, *segmented_train.shape[1:]))
    for e in range(EPOCHS):
        print(f"Epoch: {e+1}/{EPOCHS}")
        gen_perm = lambda : np.random.permutation(range(len(real_train_batched)))
        perm = gen_perm()
        real_train_batched_gen = real_train_batched[perm]
        segmented_train_batched_gen = segmented_train_batched[perm]
        real_train_batched_disc = real_train_batched[perm]
        segmented_train_batched_disc = segmented_train_batched[perm]

        pack = zip(real_train_batched_gen, segmented_train_batched_gen, real_train_batched_disc, segmented_train_batched_disc)
        for i, (b_real_gen, b_segm_gen, b_real_disc, b_segm_disc) in enumerate(pack):
            print(".", end="")
            let_the_magic_happen(b_segm_gen, b_real_gen, b_segm_disc, b_real_disc, alpha=tf.constant(0.00000005))


@tf.function
def let_the_magic_happen_discriminator(batch_segmented_gen, batch_real_gen, batch_segmented_disc, batch_real_disc):
    fake_real_images = generator_segm_to_real(batch_segmented_gen, training = False)
    fake_segmented_images = generator_real_to_segm(batch_real_gen, training = False)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as disc_tape:
        real_real_pred = discriminator_real(batch_real_disc, training=True)
        real_fake_pred = discriminator_real(fake_real_images, training=True)

        segm_real_pred = discriminator_segm(batch_segmented_disc, training=True)
        segm_fake_pred = discriminator_segm(fake_segmented_images, training=True)

        segm_disc_loss = discriminator_loss(segm_real_pred, segm_fake_pred)
        real_disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_real_pred, real_fake_pred)

    segm_disc_grad = disc_tape.gradient(segm_disc_loss, discriminator_segm.trainable_weights)
    real_disc_grad = disc_tape.gradient(real_disc_loss, discriminator_real.trainable_weights)

    segm_disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(segm_disc_grad , discriminator_segm.trainable_weights))
    real_disc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(real_disc_grad , discriminator_real.trainable_weights))

@tf.function
def let_the_magic_happen_generator(batch_segmented_gen, batch_real_gen, alpha):
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as gen_tape:
        fake_real_images = generator_segm_to_real(batch_segmented_gen, training = True)
        fake_segmented_images = generator_real_to_segm(batch_real_gen, training = True)
        fake_real_images_pred = discriminator_real(fake_real_images, training=False)
        fake_segmented_images_pred = discriminator_segm(fake_segmented_images, training=False)

        batch_real_gen_reconstruction = generator_segm_to_real(fake_segmented_images, training=True)
        batch_segmented_gen_reconstruction = generator_real_to_segm(fake_real_images, training=True)

        reconstruction_loss = alpha * (
            tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()(batch_segmented_gen, batch_segmented_gen_reconstruction) +
            tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()(batch_real_gen, batch_real_gen_reconstruction)
        )
        # tf.print(reconstruction_loss)
        # tf.print(generator_loss(fake_real_images_pred))
        # tf.print(generator_loss(fake_segmented_images_pred))

        segm_to_real_gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_real_images_pred) + reconstruction_loss
        real_to_segm_gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_segmented_images_pred) + reconstruction_loss


    real_to_segm_gen_grad = gen_tape.gradient(real_to_segm_gen_loss, generator_real_to_segm.trainable_weights)
    segm_to_real_gen_grad = gen_tape.gradient(segm_to_real_gen_loss, generator_segm_to_real.trainable_weights)

    real_to_segm_gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(real_to_segm_gen_grad , generator_real_to_segm.trainable_weights))
    segm_to_real_gen_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(segm_to_real_gen_grad , generator_segm_to_real.trainable_weights))

def let_the_magic_happen(batch_segmented_gen, batch_real_gen, batch_segmented_disc, batch_real_disc, alpha):
    let_the_magic_happen_discriminator(batch_segmented_gen, batch_real_gen, batch_segmented_disc, batch_real_disc)
    if tf.random.uniform([1]) < 0.2 :
        let_the_magic_happen_generator(batch_segmented_gen, batch_real_gen, alpha = alpha)
        let_the_magic_happen_discriminator(batch_segmented_gen, batch_real_gen, batch_segmented_disc, batch_real_disc)
@tf.function
def generator_loss(fake_pred) :
    return tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()(tf.ones_like(fake_pred), fake_pred)

@tf.function
def discriminator_loss(real_pred, fake_pred):
    return tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()(
        tf.concat((tf.ones_like(real_pred) - 5e-2, tf.zeros_like(fake_pred)),axis=0),
        tf.concat((real_pred, fake_pred),axis=0),
    )
```

The generators are 2 U-Net where the discriminator are 2 LeNet (also tried with PatchGAN, same thing happens)

I've also already tried with MAE instead of BCE