# import "tensorflow.keras.applications" could not be resolved (reportMissingImports) in google-colaboratory

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I am trying to import `tensorflow.keras.applications` in Google Colab. The imported module works fine. There is no compilation error. But, I am being shown a yellow curved underline, kind of a warning.

Error:

[image]

What is the problem that leads to such a warning?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code  or error as text in your question, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one experiencing this, and it does not happen only in Google Colab. It is a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000250/import-tensorflow-keras-could-not-be-resolved-after-upgrading-to-tensorflow-2/71838765#71838765) in Tensorflow.

Since it is just a warning you could ignore it. However if you like having code completion like I do you can substitute your imports from this:

```
import tensorflow.keras.x
```

To this:

```
import keras.api._v2.keras.x
```

Where `x` is the import you want to get.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try it?