# Can't resolve warning while importing tensorflow in colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, warnings

It keeps on showing this yellow line under every import from Tensorflow in google colaboratory. I wonder why is this happening?

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.model import Sequential
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing this too. It's a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838765/14774959) in TensorFlow. If you try executing the code everything will work fine, it's just a warning. However, if you want to make the warning go away you can replace all imports that start with `tensorflow.keras` with `keras.api._v2.keras`.

In your case:

```
from keras.api._v2.keras import layers
from keras.api._v2.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from keras.api._v2.keras import Sequential
```