# Error in the importing keras in raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, keras, raspberry-pi, tensorflow2.0

I followed this Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1BmKSYZUi8 and started to make a model of 3 traffic signs and i followed the same steps as shown in the video and generated the python file and model

I was so excited that my camera would detect these 3 road signs but to my surprise, I got some errors related to TensorFlow and Keras. I hope you don't mind helping me or giving me some direction. I think this is related to importing TensorFlow for Keras or something else.

Does Keras or Google have some tech support for solving this problem? like this

My installed versions are

- Python 3.9.2
- Keras 2.11.0
- Tensorflow 1.9.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 6, in <module>
    import tensorflow.keras
  line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import
  line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
```

I am expecting the code to run, I tried differently  methods, [Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved after upgrading to TensorFlow 2.8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000250/import-tensorflow-keras-could-not-be-resolved-after-upgrading-to-tensorflow-2)

but, this is for visual basics do you have some steps like this for the Raspberry pi 4, Python

Comment: please contact the author of the youtube video for support. -- welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Comment: Tensorflow 1.9 does not support Python 3.9, not sure how you got installed, but that is your actual problem to solve.

Comment: Tensorflow 1.9 was released in 2018. You may want to find newer guides.