# Getting errors in google collab tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm utilizing a google collab tutorial to teach myself to train custom magic wand model (which is an IMU-based model for recognizing gestures on an Arduino Nano BLE Sense 33; the tutorial uses python). This is the link: https://colab.research.google.com/github/tinyMLx/colabs/blob/master/4-8-11-CustomMagicWand.ipynb#scrollTo=yHO0QoaKInIw. Also, here is a youtube video of a walkthrough of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKRdQHO7tIY&list=LLRdgYEizxz-CLAtJM8LiTjA&index=15 starts at 31:12. But I'm getting the following errors.

Under the "Train your Model" section, the following code produces the following error:

```
# Run training
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=validation_ds,
                    callbacks=[modelCheckpointCallback])

Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-cd9dcc0dd1fe> in <cell line: 16>()
     14 
     15 # Run training
---> 16 history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=EPOCHS, validation_data=validation_ds,
     17                     callbacks=[modelCheckpointCallback])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1051, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 142, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 268, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2156, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5707, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 12)).
```

I'm also getting a warning (with green highlights) for under the "Import Packages and Set Constants" sections (which I think isn't the direct reason for the above error, but I could be wrong; it's probably best to get this resolved either way though):

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

Import "tensorflow.keras" could not be resolved
Import "tensorflow.keras.preprocessing" could not be resolved
```

Tbh I think this is mostly a syntax error that anyone who has experience in python could help out with (even without knowing about magic wands), but I don't really have much prior experience with python (just a few classes I took several years ago). And I'm following the tutorial exactly so the error must stem from either changes in the software over time (in which case I would need to know what to edit to make it work currently) or I didn't download something that the video didn't mention.

Comment: This tells you where to look and what to fix: ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 12)).

Comment: Look into this for the Import error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71000250/import-tensorflow-keras-could-not-be-resolved-after-upgrading-to-tensorflow-2

Comment: The warnings are coming from your editor, not from Python.  If the code runs, and it seems to, just ignore the editor warnings for now.